# selection of checkbox in facebox and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebox

HTML:

```
{% for item in result %}
       <tr id="row">
         <td><input name="item" type="checkbox" value="{{ item.number }}"></td>
         <td contenteditable id="col1">{{ item.foo }}</td>
         <td contenteditable id="col4">{{ item.bar }}</td>
       </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I am using `facebox` . Where I want to show the single row in the `facebox` which ever i checked ( checked the `checkbox`, which is in `first <td>` ). Jquery is:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#edit').click(function() {
        jQuery.facebox({ div: '#row' })
        return false;
    });
});
```

This jquery is giving me the first `row` only.

Comment: ID attributes must begin with a letter (`[A-Za-z]`) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits (`[0-9]`), hyphens (`-`), underscores (`_`), colons (`:`), and periods (`.`). http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#h-6.2 - furthermore, **IDs are unique, meaning only one element in the DOM can have a given ID at any time** -- Anything more than that and jQuery will NEVER find your elements because `getElementById()` only returns ONE element

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the same "id" value for more than one element in a page.

You can change that from "id" to "class" and it (might) work. It's hard to tell what exactly you're doing.

```
  <tr class='row'>
    <!-- ... -->
  </tr>
```

then

```
    // ...
    jQuery.facebox({div: '.row'});
```

Of course you could just find the `<tr>` elements directly:

```
    jQuery.facebox({div: 'tr'});
```